# Stack 8 - Metro Style Stack Exchange Reader for Windows 8

Tags: app, windows

**Description**

Make the most of all Stack Exchange sites in one place. Stack 8 helps you to keep track of all your favourites Stack Exchange sites making easier to find questions and answers.

**Features**

- Select your favourites Stack Exchange sites.
- See the newest, featured and not answered questions of your selected sites.
- Search questions in the app using the Search Charm or just typing when in full screen mode.
- Live tiles.
- Share questions with your friends and colleagues.
- Pin questions to start screen to easy access.

**Code**
Written in C# & Xaml

**V1.0**

First release

**Main Screen:**
[image]

**Select Sites:**
[image]

**Semantic Zoom:**
[image]

**Search:**
[image]

**Snapped View:**
[image]

**Future Versions**

- Support for logging

**Support, Feedback, Contact**

On my [profile](https://stackapps.com/users/20475/estebane97)